# Remove Item From Multidimensional Array using knockout

Tags: knockout.js

I have a Multidimensional Array like this below

```
"ContactsList":[[{"id":73,"title":"IT Manager"},{"id":74,"title":"Manager"}],
[{"id":75,"title":"Developer"},{"id":76,"title":"Salesperson"},{"id":77,"title":"Person"}]]
```

In the above structure i want to remove `{"id":73,"title":"IT Manager"}` first object from first array, but knockout does't allow me to do that.

Comment: Can you clarify what "knockout doesn't allow me" means?  Please show the code that isn't working and explain what error you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the full code, I am guessing but I think I understand the issue.

An observable array observes only the element of the array. It does not observe the *contents* of the elements, unless you specifically make them observable.

For example you could change the `id` or `title` values on any object, and it will not trigger an update. Knockout was told to observe the array items only.

You need to map each nested array to an observable array as well. Doing this means removal of an item in the nested array will trigger knockout's binding. Here is some sample code:

```js
var contactsList = [
  [{
    "id": 73,
    "title": "IT Manager"
  }, {
    "id": 74,
    "title": "Manager"
  }],
  [{
    "id": 75,
    "title": "Developer"
  }, {
    "id": 76,
    "title": "Salesperson"
  }, {
    "id": 77,
    "title": "Person"
  }]
];

var viewModel = function(data) {
  var self = this;

  // convert nested-arrays to observable arrays
  var tmp = ko.utils.arrayMap(data, function(item) {
    return ko.observableArray(item);
  });
  // main array 
  self.Data = ko.observableArray(tmp);
  self.Error = ko.observable("");
  self.RemoveFirst = function() {
    // get first element - should be an observableArray
    var first = self.Data()[0];
    // check it's not null
    if (first) {
      console.log(typeof first);
      console.log("item: " + ko.toJSON(first));
      // get first sub-element
      var subelement = first()[0];
      if (subelement) {
       first.remove(subelement);
        //first.remove(subelement);
        self.Error("Removed " + ko.toJSON(subelement));
        // might want to check for empty array and remove 'first' here
      }
    } else {
      self.Error("No items");
    }
  }
};

var vm = new viewModel(contactsList);
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div data-bind="foreach: Data">
  <b>Item <span data-bind="text: $index"></span></b>
  <p>
  
  </p>
  <ul data-bind="foreach: $data">
    <li>
      <span data-bind="text: id"></span>&nbsp;
      <span data-bind="text: title"></span>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <hr/>
</div>
<button data-bind="click: RemoveFirst">
  Remove First
</button>
<div style="color: red" data-bind="text: Error">
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Patrick, thank you so much, it's been a greet help for me, thanks again

Comment: Hi Patrick, i have a problem from couple of days, and did't find any luck, and a real wory about this, i have created a question on SO, can you have a look please, it will really thankfull to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34675368/apply-validation-on-ko-computed-using-knockout-js